# ASP MVC: ActionFilter attribute -> RedirectToRouteResult always redirect to HTTP GET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, action-filter

I have an ActionFilter attribute at the top of my controller.

```
[HandleError]
[MyActionFilter]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
  ...
}
```

When an action is received, i want to add/change some route values and then redirect to a correct route.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { lang = langName, controller = controllerName, action = actionName, id = idName }));
```

This is working fine. However, the redirection is **always** set to HTTP GET, and since some of my actions are set to receive only HTTP POST, it fails.

Is there any way to make the redirection be HTTP POST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the redirection be HTTP POST?

No. The verb GET is at the very base of the definition of a redirect in the HTTP specification. It simply doesn't make sense to talk about *an HTTP redirect* and an HTTP verb different than GET.

Instead of redirecting you could return a view directly:

```
var result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/SomeView.cshtml",
};
result.Model = new MyViewModel();
filterContext.Result = result;
```

Comment: ViewResult Model property is ready only. You probably want to use result.ViewData.Model

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are **redirecting** your users to another action. This in **HTTP protocol** means that you send codes **301**, **302**, or **303** alongside your response to clients' browser.

Browser on the other hand always sends an HTTP Get in reaction to an HTTP redirection.

Thus, your answer is:

### No